# How to send new date to next page using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Background**:I have one button on my test.aspx page, I also have a label on this page called `lblSelectedDate` . This button named `b1` sends the date in the label to si.aspx. *This works properly*.

**Problem**: Lets say for example for test.aspx on page load the default value of `lblSelectedDate` is 7/1/2017;  pressing `b1` sends that date successfully to si.aspx. But it sends 7/1/2017 looking at my snippet below it adds a day so the  date should be 7/2/2017 right?

Not sure what I am missing.

Here is the snippet that sends the date, on `b1` click event:

```
DateTime lblHiddenDate = Convert.ToDateTime(lblSelectedDate.Text);
Response.Redirect("si.aspx?lblDateFull=" + lblHiddenDate.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: What does it send to next page instead of `7/2/2017`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya "But it sends 7/1/2017"

Comment: You should probably use `DateTime.ParseExact()` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime` to get the correct date from the string. It may very well be a UTC issue you're seeing. Debug and see what the value of `lblHiddenDate` is.

Comment: @TommyMcGee before calling .Redirect method set your HiddenDate to value as you want don't do it on redirection.

Comment: Are you doing any operation in the date value in the next page?  Did you debug and check what value is being passed ? You can use toddler to observe the value being passed in the url

Comment: I would send it in another format than the potentially ambiguous one provided by ToShortDateString. ISO format, or a timestamp format would be a lot more reliable.

Comment: if you put a break point right after the convert statement, what is the datetime value in lblHiddenDate?

Comment: *"so the date should be 7/2/2017 right?"* I guess that depends on your culture. Here in the UK your snippet returns 8/1/2017 (7 of January + 1 day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Session State:

```
    protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["SomeDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(lblSelectedDate.Text).AddDays(1);
         Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dateText = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["SomeDate"]);
    }
```